# Update an item within an observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I have an `observableArray`

```
self.items= ko.observableArray([]);
```

that contains Items of the following

```
self.item = function () {
        this.number
    };
```

I have another object People

```
self.people = ko.observableArray([]);
```

which which is an `observableArray` of  a `person` obj that has an instance of the `items` `observableArray`

I can add to these fine and everything is working as it should.

The problem comes when I try to edit an `item` within the `items` array within a `person`.

This is how the items are displayed.

```
<!-- ko foreach:  items-->
    <input class="number" data-bind="value: number" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Is there a way to tie down the change to a specific item?

Comment: How are you updating an item?

Comment: Also, if you want properties of item changing causing the item changing in the UI you need to make its properties observables

Comment: From your description all persons have a reference to the same `self.items` so it's logical that when you modify an item all persons are impacted. If you don't want that, each person should have its very own observable array of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you nest your view models properly, Knockout will bind inputs to the specific items correctly without extra work on your part. You haven't been 100% clear about what your view models look like, but here's a setup that should work.

Supposing your two viewmodels look like this:

```
var Item = function(name, nr) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.number = ko.observable(nr);
};

var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.items = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

and your root view model has an `observableArray` of `people` as mentioned in the question, like this:

```
var vm = { people: ko.observableArray([]) }
```

With this, you can add `new Person` objects to the `people` array, and give those people individual `Item` objects in their `items` arrays.

The following view will generate `input` fields for every single item, where changes are "tied to specific items":

```html
<div data-bind='foreach: people'>
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <!-- ko foreach:  items-->
      <span data-bind="text: name"></span>:
      <input class="number" data-bind="value: number" />
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bevtK/) for a demo.